# python dynamically create pandas dataframe for class objects found in different folders

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make python read through an excel file, and then retrieve data from multiple .csv files located in multiple folders.

Currently, the code I have for doing this is:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

#Opening 'Test Tracker.xlsx' to find entities to download
TEST = pd.ExcelFile("Trackers\TEST Tracker.xlsx")
df1 = TEST.parse("Entries")

values1 = df1[['Name', 'Location', 'Date', 'TimeO', 'TimeC', 'Check_2',
           'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'VWAP', '$Volume', 'Trades']]

#Searching for every row that contains the value 'X' in the column 'Check_2'
rdf1 = values1[values1.Check_2.str.contains("X")]

#Printing dataframe to check
print("First Dataframe")
print(rdf1)
```

This produces the following:

```
     Name  Location      Date     TimeO  ... Volume VWAP  $Volume  Trades
0  Orange  New York  20200501  15:30:00  ...    NaN  NaN      NaN     NaN
1   Apple     Minsk  20200505  15:30:00  ...    NaN  NaN      NaN     NaN

[2 rows x 14 columns]
```

Continue snippet:

```
#Creating class 'Fruit' to create a list for each entity to download
class Fruit:
    def __init__(self, Name, Location, Date):
        self.Name = Name
        self.Location = Location
        self.Date = Date

#creating a list for the class objects
Fruits = []

#Putting each class object in the list 'Fruits'
for index, rows in rdf1.iterrows():
    Fruitslist = [rows.Name, rows.Location, rows.Date]
    Fruits.append(Fruitslist)

print("List of Fruits to download data from")
print(Fruits)
```

This produces:

```
[['Orange', 'New York', 20200501], ['Apple', 'Minsk', 20200505]]
```

Then the part I have issues with. The .csv files are located in folders named after the 'Name' of the fruit, and the 'Location' of the fruit. The dynamic path directory would be:

> 'Entities\'Location'\'Name'\TwoHours.csv'

an example of this is:

> 'Entities\New York\Orange\TwoHours.csv'

I am trying to create panda dataframes for each .csv file for the objects that are in the list 'Fruits'.

```
#Finding the folder for each entity, located in 'Entities\\"Location"\\"Name"\\TwoHours.csv', and creating a dataframe for each one. This is where i struggle.

gbl = globals()
def pathlocation(Name, Location):
    dest_dir = os.path.join('Entities', Location, Name)
    csv_file = os.path.join(dest_dir, 'TwoHours.csv')
    for fruit in Fruits:
        data = rdf1(Fruits[fruit])
        gbl[Fruits[fruit]+str(fruit)] = pd.DataFrame(data)
        col_list = ['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'VWAP', 'Trades']
        df3 = pd.read_csv(csv_file, usecols=col_list, sep=";")
        print("All Dataframes")
        print(df3)
```

Unfortunately I am unable to figure out how to achieve this. The abovementioned code should hopefully kind of illustrate what I am trying to do, but it obviously does not work.

I hope someone here can help me out to create the dynamic dataframes. Thanks!

EDIT:
Thanks to XXavier this now works. The code that made the final part work is:

```
#Generating dataframes from classobjects
for idx, rows in rdf1.iterrows():
    fle = os.path.join('Entities', rows.Location, rows.Name, 'TwoHours.csv')
    col_list = ['Name', 'Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'VWAP', 'Trades']
    df3 = pd.read_csv(fle, usecols=col_list, sep=";")
    Fruits.append(df3)

print("List of Fruits to download data from")
print(Fruits)

fulldf = pd.concat(Fruits)
print(fulldf)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use os.walk() to recursively find all the csv's

```
import os, re
fruits= []
rt = "c:/" #change this to the root folder

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rt):
    for fname in files:
        if re.match("^.*.csv$", fname):
            frame = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root, fname))
            fruits.append(frame) 

df = pd.concat(fruits)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately this does not seem to work, as I am getting an error: 'cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid'. Also, 2 folders are dynamic. So the folder to look in is 'Entities\\"Location"\\"Name"\\TwoHours.csv', where "Location" and "Name" are both dynamic. I don't understand how to append this code to make that work unfortunately. Could you help me out with that?

Comment: when you say dynamic, where are you getting the name of the folder? user input? is the newest folder? Were there other csv's in the similar and/or other folders that you do not want to read? Do the names of csv's always remain the same but the path changes?

Comment: The name of the folder / path is retreived from "TEST Tracker.xlsx". If searches for any row that has an "X" in the column "Check 2", and then it creates a list of all the rows that fit that criteria and retreives "Location" and "Name". Then the folders where the .csv files are found are located in 'Entities\\"Location"\\"Name"\\TwoHours.csv', so for example 'Entities\\New York\\Orange\\TwoHours.csv'. There are folders in 'Entities\\New York\\' that should not be read, and files in ''Entities\\New York\\Orange\\' that shouldn't be read either. Only 'Entities\\"Location"\\"Name"\\TwoHours.csv'

Comment: I hope that clarifies your question

Comment: Can you try this, after you get the rdf1
`lst=[]`
`for idx, rows in rdf1.iterrows():`
    `fle = os.path.join('Entities', rows.Location, rows.Name, 'TwoHours.csv')`
    `col_list = ['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'VWAP', 'Trades']`
   `df3 = pd.read_csv(fle, usecols=col_list, sep=";")`
   ``lst.append(df3)``

Comment: Yes that worked perfectly! Thank you so much man this has costed me so much time. Ill update my post with the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Hey Xxavier, I hope that this is a good way to contact you. I am still having issues with the same problem as your list solution stores data in one 'cell', if that makes sense. the dataframes that have been put in the list should be reconverted to one dataframe so that this can be used for index match, but I really can't figure out how to do this. could you lend a hand?

Comment: You df3 is a list of dataframes correct? Are you saying each of those dataframe stores the data it read in one cell? Did you do `df = pd.concat(fruits)` at the end to combine all the datasets together?

Comment: Dude thank you,  ever since I got your comment I have been struggling to figure this out, so for over a day hahaha. Thanks a lot man!! ill update the answer again.